# How to setup granular privileges on GCS?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am working on a project where I would like a developer to have access to read/write to GCS, but not necessarily have access to uploading code in App Engine. I don't see options in the web console for specifying rights access. How can I setup specific privileges that I'd like a user to have? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, if you want a team member not to be allowed to deploy the application and modify or configure its resources, him/her must have only "can View" access level for a project.

Then you have to set the respective permission (WRITE) for a bucket scoped to "Google account email address" (email address of your developer) in you case.

As GCS documentation says, there are three ways to specify ACLs to buckets and objects, using:

1. The acl query string parameter to specify ACLs for certain scopes ([here](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#aclquery))
2. The x-goog-acl request header to specify predefined ACLs ([here](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#extension))
3. The defaultObjectACL query string parameter to change the default object ACL for all objects in a certain bucket ([here](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#changingdefaultobject))